# NPM add extra code depending on build args

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay so I have some node packages. They contain classes, and they can be exported by module.exports easily.

Here is an example of the end of the file:

```
module.exports.FlarePlayIcon = FlarePlayIcon;
module.exports.FlarePauseIcon = FlarePauseIcon;
module.exports.VolumeIcon = FlareVolumeIcon;
module.exports.LoadingIcon = FlareLoadingIcon;
```

full file: https://github.com/FlareMediaPlayer/FlareIcons/blob/master/src/flare-icons.js

Everything builds and compiles as expected. Now what I have been googling for hours and can't exactly get to work is adding a way to export the classes in a "global mode" so that there is some sort added on script to make the classes global, probably looking something like this:

```
window.Flare = Flare || {};
Flare.FlarePlayIcon = FlarePlayIcon;
```

So essentially I want to be able to switch on and off a way add the classes to global scope using a build script, or make file, but I'm open to any idea. I usually use browserify to prepair a script for front end use if that information is of any value.

EDIT:
so what I need is a way to pass a variable or flag to do this:

```
if (mode === "global") {

    window.Flare = Flare || {};
    window.Flare.FlarePlayIcon = FlarePlayIcon;
    window.Flare.FlarePauseIcon = FlarePauseIcon;
    window.Flare.VolumeIcon = FlareVolumeIcon;
    window.Flare.LoadingIcon = FlareLoadingIcon;

} else {

    module.exports.FlarePlayIcon = FlarePlayIcon;
    module.exports.FlarePauseIcon = FlarePauseIcon;
    module.exports.VolumeIcon = FlareVolumeIcon;
    module.exports.LoadingIcon = FlareLoadingIcon;

}
```

What can I put in the conditional statement to make it work?

Comment: What's your use case? Is it to test to see if it's in a browser?

Comment: Okay so sometimes its going to part of a bigger stand alone plugin, but I would also like to be able to include the script and be able to use the icons freely.

Comment: I don't use browserify so what I normally do is detect if `module` exists. If it does I can be sure it's in node.js. If not I assume it's in a browser. Then I export what I need globally with all the assumptions I can make from that. Would that work for you?

Comment: That was my first try, but the catch is it needs browserify or something similar because this module requires another. In order to resolve the require calls it will still need to be run through npm so it will still say module exists.

Comment: Then can you do the opposite? Check if `window` exists (I'm fairly sure it doesn't on node). Caveat: strict mode may break this in browsers.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I'm looking for, I don't need it to detect wether its running in node, or on front end browser. It will always run on the front end, but I want it to run in 2 modes, normal, and global where classes are exposed to the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The file needs to be parsed and the enviroment variables can be replaced with string literals. There are a few plugins that do this like babel. In this case I'm using envify.
inside the make file:

```
browserify src/flare-icons.js -t [ envify purge --MODE global ] | \...
```

so then

```
console.log(process.env.MODE);
```

evalueates to "global"

https://github.com/hughsk/envify#purging-processenv

http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-inline-environment-variables/